# How to create a custom header with print module and tcpdf

Tags: files

I'm using [print](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) module to generate pdf files of the articles. I'm using tcpdf library, I couldn't find the header options in the settings page. I can see options for Logo and footer, but no header options.

When I tried to get the pdf file. In the header section, there appears logo in the left corner and title of the article on the right corner. I was looking for the header settings in such a way to fix header with an image and nothing else.

I tried to google it but ended with empty hands. This [article](http://www.cameronandwilding.com/blog/jos%C3%A9/custom-pdf-generation-tcpdf), suggests to create sub-class of tcpdf - I don't know where to create, I mean where to integrate the code??. I also found `views PDF` module to set header - I don't think it will be a better option.

Is there any better way to set custom header (as image).

Answer (score 0):

Since there's not an option for that, you'll need to work on the code, and you have two different options there.

First, work on your theme's print.css file and add something like

```
.article-name{display:none}
```

If it has none, add on to its .info file with

```
stylesheets[print][] = 'css/print.css';
```

Second, if you need "bigger" changes not achievable trough css (or just need too many), copy the print template from the print module to your theme template's folder and edit at wish.

---

consider however that the cas changes will be applied to every page you will print, and the template changes to every page printed trough the print module, both pdf and all the others.

Comment: I made the changes, but there is no change in the output. I don't what you are trying to suggest.

Comment: and clear the cache for the changes to be registered

Comment: I didn't get your second point - copy print template from print module to your theme template's folder. I couldn't find print template in print module.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class PrintTCPDF_No_Headers extends PrintTCPDF {
  public function Header() {
    if ($this->page > 1){
      return;
    }
    parent::Header();
  }
}
```

you try out this [more detials for idea](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127645/custom-generate-pdf-with-the-header-displaying-only-in-the-first-page)